# Problems with PhoneGap with Facebook Connect integration

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to use the new PhoneGap Facebook Connect plugin, which is supposed to work with just a few lines of code. https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect

PhoneGap v1.2.0

In Eclipse, I have built the sample project included with the plugin and have added my app_id and app_secret and put all files where necessary. It seems like I have done everything right, but the buttons do the following:

- Login: Alerts "not logged in" (even though I am logged in to Facebook both through the app and the browser)
- Me: Alerts "An active access token mst be used to query information about the current user. Type: OAuthException
- Get Session: Alerts "undefined"
- Get Login: Loads a facebook page in the browser which says "an error occurred. Please try again later"
- Logout: Alerts "auth.statusChange event"

What have I done wrong? I have a killer app waiting to be released which is dependent on this Facebook integration and I'm anxious to release it!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the phonegap core implementation.

The official Android Facebook plugin opens a dialog for facebook authentication.

This all happens threaded within phonegap. 
They used however plain threading instead of AsyncTask driven threads.

The AsyncTask concept allows background tasks to be displayed within the main UI thread.

I have created a fork for phonegap 1.2 called tmaus.

Using the forked phonegap, you would be able to properly login into facebook, 
but the handling of the session_data is still broken.

Comment: The only ability I need is for the user to click a "Share on Facebook" button, which will post some data from my app to their wall. I guess I don't need to bother with giving the user the ability to log in to Facebook if they are not already. Maybe I can just show the share button if they are already logged in. Will your fork let me do this?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at gitbub/callback-android 
You will find my fork (tmaus) which has not been confirmed yet.